# Unable to access php $_GET variable due to htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using this .htaccess code for my web application, It's working fine but i am unable to access `$_GET` variables.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?$1&p=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?$1
```

The URL i use right now is `http://www.website.com/mainpage/subpage/id/` But if i do something like this `http://www.website.com/mainpage/subpage/id/?template=new` I cannot access the `$_GET['template']` variable, I am pretty sure `htaccess` is causing this but i don't know how to proceed forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `QSA` flag so that query strings get appended to the end of your rewrite targets:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?$1&p=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```